# Need a way to query MongoDB collection, and ngRepeat beginning at specific point

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

is there a way to query a MongoDB collection, return the results, use an AngularJS ng-repeat to iterate through the results, BUT BEGIN the iteration at a specific position in the results, somewhere in the middle for example?

I am currently returning a query to an angular view; a category of materials. Then i have my view set up to paginate(ng-repeat) through the results. However, no matter what material I click on to bring me into the view (from a different view), the ng-repeat always starts at the beginning of the materials list, rather than on the material i clicked. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you use the mongo query to begin in middle? I mean instead of using ng-repeat to start at a specific location, you can just get the data needed using `skip` and `limit` in mongo.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe the mongodb part has anything to do with the actual question but ill give you 2 options:
The quick way:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="$index >= myCtrl.startPoint">
```

While this will do the trick you might want to do the `ng-show` expression with a filter.  In addition you might run into performance issues.  You should also use the `track by` feature.

A better way would be to have a `filteredData` model for the ng-repeat and do the correct filtering once per action.  You would have to make sure yourself that the model is updated on every data change and every user input.

There are many choices in between these 2 options but what to use depends on your needs. For instance - does user input change frequently? Is your data updated frequently? etc.